# "//" ......" //]]>" appears on the page when " //<![CDATA[ " ....."//]]>" are used to wrap a JS code

Tags: jsf, knockout.js

I'm trying to add the html5 drag 'n drop upload file on my JSF web page so i had to add this script into it

```
<script type="text/html" id="template-uploads">

  //<![CDATA[


      <div data-bind="visible: showTotalProgress()">
            <div>
                <span data-bind="text: uploadSpeedFormatted()"></span>
                <span data-bind="text: timeRemainingFormatted()" style="float: right;"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="uploadimage-totalprogress">
                <div class="uploadimage-totalprogressbar" style="width: 0%;" data-bind="style: { width: totalProgress() + '%' }"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-bind="foreach: uploads">
            <div class="uploadimage-upload" data-bind="css: { 'uploadimage-uploadcompleted': uploadCompleted() }">
                <div class="uploadimage-fileinfo">
                    <strong data-bind="text: fileName"></strong>
                    <span data-bind="text: fileSizeFormated"></span>
                    <span class="uploadimage-progresspct" data-bind="visible: uploadProgress() < 100"><span data-bind="text: uploadSpeedFormatted()"></span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="uploadimage-progress">
                    <div class="uploadimage-progressbar" style="width: 0%;" data-bind="style: { width: uploadProgress() + '%' }"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    //]]>
    </script>
```

if i take out the cdata tag which is around my script i get this error :

> The value of attribute "data-bind" associated with an element type
>   "span" must not contain the '<' character.

Comment: The title of your question seems to describe a different problem than what you're talking about.

Comment: I don't see any JavaScript here

Comment: Roman : i edited my post.

Comment: Doorknob : indeed , you are right. it's kinda a template but it generates the same problem with the "<" caracter like in JS and i don't know how to deal with this.

Answer (score 1):

The script you've posted is a text/html script which acts as a template in knockout. That id is required for knockout to reference the template.

As for the CDATA sections, unless you're using XML you can take them out.

Comment: I'm sorry , i'm not good in english and i'm not sure i've understood your answer. you said that id is required (obviousely as i got an error when i get rid of it ) but then you said that i can delete it ?

Comment: You can take out `//<![CDATA[` and `//]]>`.

Comment: i said what happens when i take out of the //<![CDATA[ and //]]> jamie!